# High CPU usage when playing GIFs

Tags: android, gif, android-glide

I am displaying GIFs in a RecyclerView. Code:

```
Glide.with(acitivity)
  .load(url)
  .placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder)
  .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
  .listener(listener)
  .into(viewHolder.imageView);
```

If I keep the Fragment containing this RecyclerView open, very high amount of CPU (~40%) is used by the app. And the phone heats up if I use the Fragment for 1-2 minutes. Is it normal for GIFs? Am I doing anything wrong here?

Comment: You should open up a performance profiler in android studio and look at what is going on, perhaps systrace may help.

Comment: Performance profiler show highest invocation counts for: `android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run 
android.view.Choreographer.doFrame 
android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks 
android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run 
android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw 
android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw 
android.view.ThreadedRenderer.draw`

Comment: try to use fresco by facebook, it's good library.

Comment: Well i guess it would be expected potentially as a gif is just a collection of images that are played over a sequence of time. If you have large frames being rendered then it very well could be expected as loading images vs a video is radically difference in terms of performance.

Comment: yeah. checked with glide contributors and got similar response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got response from Glide contributors on Github. Here is what they say -

> High CPU consumption is normal. Glide does this to save memory and  eventually the evil OOM Exceptions.

Suggestions -

> 1. Use static `Bitmap` image for preview, avoid auto-play.
> 2. Use timeout or `setLoopCount` on `GlideDrawable/GifDrawable`

More: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1029

Edit:

Check this issue if you are using ViewPager: https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1028